# React Native - How to submit a Formik from Header

Tags: react-native, formik, use-effect, usecallback

I'm new to Formik and React Native. Currently, my goal is to submit a form via the Navigation header. All the examples I found are to submit the form from the screen page itself. I need help figure out how to properly use the **handleSubmit** and **onSubmit** property and **setParams** to pass the value to the navigation header properly.

Right now, I'm stuck by not sending the values from the form to the useCallBack hook.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Button, Text} from 'react-native';
import {Input} from 'react-native-elements';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import Colors from '../../constants/Colors';
import {
  HeaderButtons,
  HeaderButton,
  Item,
} from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import {Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import {CommonActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as prodActions from '../../store/actions/products';
import {Formik} from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const AddProduct = ({navigation}) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const submitHandler = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(prodActions.addProduct(value));
  }, [value]);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.setParams({submitForm: submitHandler}));
  }, [submitHandler]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{title: '', description: '', imageUrl: ''}}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
          title: Yup.string().required('please input your title'),
          description: Yup.string().required('please input your description'),
          imageUrl: Yup.string()
            //.email('Please input a valid email.')
            .required('Please input an email address.'),
        })}
        onSubmit={submitHandler}
      >
        {({
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          values,
          touched,
          errors,
        }) => (
          <View>
            <Input
              label="Title"
              labelStyle={{color: Colors.accent}}
              onChangeText={handleChange('title')}
              onBlur={handleBlur('title')}
              value={values.title}
              // errorMessage={errors.title}
            />
            {touched.title && errors.title ? (
              <Text style={styles.error}>{errors.title}</Text>
            ) : null}
            <Input
              label="Description"
              labelStyle={{color: Colors.accent}}
              onChangeText={handleChange('description')}
              onBlur={handleBlur('description')}
              value={values.description}
            />
            {touched.description && errors.description ? (
              <Text style={styles.error}>{errors.description}</Text>
            ) : null}
            <Input
              label="Image URL"
              labelStyle={{color: Colors.accent}}
              onChangeText={handleChange('imageUrl')}
              onBlur={handleBlur('imageUrl')}
              value={values.imageUrl}
            />
            {touched.imageUrl && errors.imageUrl ? (
              <Text style={styles.error}>{errors.imageUrl}</Text>
            ) : null}
            <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
          </View>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </View>
  );
};

const IoniconsHeaderButton = (props) => (
  <HeaderButton
    IconComponent={Ionicons}
    iconSize={23}
    color="white"
    {...props}
  />
);

export const AddProductHeaderOptions = (navData) => {
  const updateForm = navData.route.params.submitForm;
  return {
    headerRight: () => {
      return (
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={IoniconsHeaderButton}>
          <Item title="add" iconName="save-outline" onPress={updateForm} />
        </HeaderButtons>
      );
    },
  };
};

export default AddProduct;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  error: {
    marginLeft: 8,
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'red',
  },
});
```

Comment: `const submitHandler = useCallback( ({values}) => { ... }, [] );` ... no dependency as values not in this scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using "value" variable with an empty value. You must ref all your form data, inside your < Formik > , let's use street, for an example:

```
value={values.street}
error={touched.street && !isSubmitting && errors.street}
returnKeyType="next"
onSubmitEditing={() => refs.number.current?.focus()}
ref={refs.street}
```

So declare this ref variable first:

```
const refs = {
street: useRef<any>(null),
number: useRef<any>(null),
zipCode: useRef<any>(null),
//....
```

If you don't wanna go with REF, so at least declare the variable and try it, like that:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState();
```

Also, the VALUE name is not a good variable name because there are a lot of native things using it. But, considering that you must have taken this from an example, use useState with your form or object and you should be good.

```
const [formx, setFormx] = useState();
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who use React-Navigation 5 and Formik 1.5.x+ Here is a good solution.
Declare a ref variable outside/inside of your function component to later Attach to your

```
let formRef;//or you can use const formRef = useRef(); inside function component
```

If you declare formRef outside your function component use React hook {useRef} to update the ref

```
formRef = useRef();
```

Render

```
<Formik innerRef={formRef} />
```

And finally in your header button call this

```
navigation.setOptions({
headerRight: () => (
    <Button onPress={() => {
        if (formRef.current) {
           formRef.current.handleSubmit()
        }
    }}/>
  )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which I think could be better is to use the useFormik, which gives you access to all the form handlers and form meta:

```
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    handleChange,
    isValid,
  } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {...},
    validationSchema: yupValidationSchema,
    onSubmit: (formValues) => {
      //save here...
    }
  });
```

Then you can simply pass the handleSubmit reference to your right header navigation using the useLayoutEffect as proposed in the official documentation:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerRight: () => {
      return (
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={IoniconsHeaderButton}>
          <Item title="add" iconName="save-outline" onPress={handleSubmit}/>
       </HeaderButtons>
    );
  }
});
```

});

This approach is clear in my opinion, since you don't need to handle all the structural disadvantages  of using the renderProps approach with

```
<Formkik>
  {({ handleSubmit }) => (
   jsx here...
  )}
</Formik>
```